# Matlab: Selecting rows related of specfic time

Tags: matlab, date

I have data from a sensor, data were recording for five days non stop. How to select specific rows, related with the certain time, e.g. 11-09-2013 11:20:00 - 11:21:49 PM ? Then, how to divide the obtained data into equal segments 2.56 seconds each?

My data looks like this:

```
0.135478690266609
0.0537606552243232
-0.0262537784874439
0.157014295458793
0.149360358715057
0.104898564517498
0.0393946692347526
...
```

and I can read time by using `datestr(data(1), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM')`

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you provide a sample from it? It's impossible to help you without knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `data` is a vector of timestamps in days.

To find the first row that comes after `11-09-2013 11:20:00 PM`, you can do:

```
target = datenum('11-09-2013 11:20:00 PM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') / 86400;
row = find(data >= target, 1, 'first');
```

To find all rows between `11-09-2013 11:20:00 PM` and `11-09-2013 11:21:49 PM`:

```
start = datenum('11-09-2013 11:20:00 PM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') / 86400;
stop = datenum('11-09-2013 11:21:49 PM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') / 86400;
rows = find(data >= start & data <= stop);
```

To get a segment of 2.56 seconds after the date `start`, set `stop` to `start + 2.56 / 86400` and use the same trick as above.

Comment: Im getting 'Empty matrix' as answer for rows

Comment: load('MyData.mat')
x=RightLimb

start = datenum('11-09-2013 11:20:00 PM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') * 1e-5;
stop = datenum('11-09-2013 11:21:49 PM', 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:MM:SS AM') * 1e-5;
rows = find(x >= start & x <= stop);

Comment: Reread the answer now that I edited it. I didn't get that the unit was _days_.

Comment: Also, the sample data you gave starts at `00-01-0000  3:14:56 AM` so I suppose there is an offset which you need to take into account.

Comment: Hmm, Simon, then why 3600 not 86400 in this case?                 And, could you tell me a bit more about this offset?
Lets say the 1st row of the data is 3:46:54 PM and the time of my interest starts 11:20 PM (which is somewhere around 121301st row)

Comment: Check that the timestamp you are looking for falls in the range between `data(1)` and `data(end)`. Alternatively, convert the timestamp you are looking for to a date to see if it is what you expect.